# Flutter not navigating to next page context error?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator

This is my code what i am doing it that on tap i need to go to another page ,but i am getting an error **Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'SHA-WAY';
    var FirstPage = ['SURGERIES','OPERTAION THEATER TECHNICIAN','DRESSINGS OR BANDAGES','PHYSIOTHERAPY','NURSE MALE|FEMALE',
      'HOSPITAL LINEN OR STAFF UNIFORM','MEDICENS(ONLY RARE INJECTIONS)','OPERATION THEATRE INSTRUMENTS|EQUIPEMENTS'];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
          // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children:  [
            Card(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => surgeries()),
                  );
                },
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.content_cut,size: 60.0,),
                      Text(FirstPage[0]),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is the class where i want to navigate,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class surgeries extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SURGERIES"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

don't know what i am doing wrong just started FLUTTER and i am stuck

Comment: did you have try this? 
Navigator.of(context).push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => surgeries()),
                  );

Comment: not working ive tried this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the approach shown in the [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes),

1. You have to define the routes in the main.dart

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

2. Then you can navigate to the First screen to another on onTap or onPressed event like this,

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

**Note: You should only have one MaterialApp in your whole app.**
For more head over to [official Page](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Comment: i dont want to go with .pushname because than after i have to remove the home property as well . Why i cant do it with navigator?

Comment: you can do with navigatorKey

Comment: @RAJASAHAB you can, [working example is here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics). But for the future project, you might try **routes** approach.

Comment: great , i've started using pushname

Answer (score 0):

Your all classes should be descendant of `MaterialApp` widget, to achieve that, wrap your class that placed on runApp method with `MaterialApp` widget, then remove all of other `MaterialApp` widgets from your widget tree.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp));
}
```

Comment: i have done that now its giving me error **MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery**

Answer (score -1):

Just tried this and work!

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'example',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      theme: ThemeData(

        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Colors.blue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
        )
      ),
      home: Esempio1()

    );
    }
}




  class Esempio1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WAKAWAKA"),
      ),
          body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("aasdasd"),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> Esempio2()));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Esempio2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("eheh"),
      ),
          body: Container(
        child: Text("AAAAA"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: return scaffold and app bar please